# How do I fetch the data from list present in root web of the root site collection?

Tags: list, security, caml, ssom

We need to populate some data on an application page. The application page is present in the layouts folder and hence is accessible via the respective site URL. There are multiple site collections. Each site collection has their own set of users (unique) who do not interfere or have rights with other sitecollections.

There is a list in Root Site collection's(the 1st site collection we create after creating a web application) root web.

I need to pull in the data from this list into the application page.

My question is **how do I access the root site collections**, root web using the SP Server Object model from any other site collections web?

Also, **what would be the security implications**, because we cannot have a  user of say site collection 2 or 3 or 4 to have any rights in the 1st site collection. Does that mean that this scenario is not possible? Is there any other workaround?

The requirement is to have a policy page which should pick up data from a list and show to users. The user wants the policy page data to be dynamically picked from the 1st item of the list. This page is an application page and hence is accessible to each user on every site collection's web. However, my concern is regarding the way to access this data from sitecollection[0].rootweb **and** regarding security implications as users of other site collections do not have any rights on sitecollection[0].

**UPDATE1**

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {                   
                    SPWeb rootSiteColRootWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb;

                    SPList spList = rootSiteColRootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyMenu");
                        if (spList != null)
                        {
                            SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
                            qry.Query =
                            @"   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
   </OrderBy>";
                            qry.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Data' />";
                            SPListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(qry);

                            contentsDiv.InnerHtml = listItems[0]["Data"].ToString();
                        }
                });
```

**Update2**

```
     SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb.Url))
                    {
                        SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;

                        SPList spList = rootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyMenu");
                        if (spList != null)
                        {
                            SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
                            qry.Query =
                            @"   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
   </OrderBy>";
                            qry.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Data' />";
                            SPListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(qry);

                            contentsDiv.InnerHtml = listItems[0]["Data"].ToString();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

The code present in both Update 1 and update 2 run successfully when user with no rights on the sitecollection on which the list is present logs in. I want to know which is better method and why?

Comment: [Is this old post linked to the above](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94919/how-to-access-root-site-collection-from-other-site-collections)? It would seem that the base question is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your origional question iv answered here about getting the root web of a site:

for the root web of the site collection:

```
SPWeb spWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPList spList = spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
```

if its the root web of the root site collection than roberts way is the right way to get the spsite root!

[SPSite URL value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95680/spsite-url-value/95687#95687)

following on about sercurity and the account being used:

sharepoint gives restricted read access so you can get to sitecolection 2 URL otherwise you wouldnt be able to. Running on server has nothing todo with it! the code is run under nt authenticated user! and defnaltly not app pool account!!

Just becasue code is run under the server doesnt mean its run under app pool account! the only way that happens is if you set runwithelevatedprivlages otherwise you would be giving all users unnessary access! To prove my point!

within your aspx.cs add the following code, it will show you the current user... it is this user that the current context is being used and it is this user that is used to access the site and _layouts files within hive!

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    string strUserName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
    Label l = new Label();
    l.id = "userID";
    l.Text = strUserName;
    this.Controls.Add(l);
}
```

If you see system account than its app pool account.... if you see a normal user account than its not running under app pool! If it is running under app pool account than you should be worried as your giving unnessary access that is aginst best practice.

how do i also know it runs under nt authenticated account? well just try and access the file as annoymous :) youll get access denied... for that you need impersonation as not even elevated privlages work!

[Application page in layouts folder accessing web application object](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95825/application-page-in-layouts-folder-accessing-web-application-object/95834#95834)

Answer (score 2):

To access the rootweb use

```
var rootWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb;
```

If your user will not have access to this collection, you must open it up in elevated privileges:

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Id))
            using (SPWeb rootWeb = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                // Do your stuff with rootWeb
            }
        }
```

Comment: Should'nt your code have been: SPWeb rootWeb=site.RootWeb?

Comment: When I know that I will access the RootWeb, then why should I open allwebs? Also I want to ask you that about your 1st line var rootWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb; can we put this directly into the runwithelevatedpriviledges?

Comment: But I am putting the line inside the runwithelevatedpriviledges.. is that possible?

Comment: Also, does site.OpenWeb() return the root web by default?

Comment: OK, thanks, I have updated my question and added some code to show my finding, would like to hear your comments on it.

Comment: Please put the question on hold as it is my mistake, I will just update it ASAP

Comment: Robert, I can confirm from my finding that a user can access the list present on a site collection to which he does not have any rights, using RunWithElevatedPrivileges (update1 and update2, both work). Can you comment on this.

Comment: Nbr1? Sorry I did not understand, I have tried this.

Comment: Probably thats what happens when we use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

Comment: I have debugged both codes by setting breakpoints in VS2012. Is that why it works, because I am debugging using VS?

Comment: Only because you insist I am using code of UPDATE 2 (without using block for SPWeb), but I have got output for both the updates 1 and 2 aswell.

Comment: Hey check this out: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95825/application-page-in-layouts-folder-accessing-web-application-object It looks like the application page does not need the RunWithelevated priviledges code at all!.. Give me your feedback on this.

Comment: Sorry but I had to unmark this answer as I have mentioned that I am using an application page, and you adviced me to "you must open it up in elevated privileges" which is incorrect for an application page as code runs under NT authenticated user account.

Comment: You mentioned "If your user will not have access to this collection, you must open it up in elevated privileges". And my update 1 and update 2 worked because its an application page. Please try to understand and don't get personal (by saying I am lost) and stick to topic please.

Comment: I'm sticking to topic. And you can say what you want, but application page or not, the current user must have at least limited access for your scenario without correct elevation to work. That is the fact

Comment: Your last comment is correct. But, my question is about application pages. And you answered that I have to elevate the privileges. I said we cannot have a user of say site collection 2 or 3 or 4 to have any rights in the 1st site collection. Well, I donot argue with you regarding using elevatedpriviledges code (I realised that we need to create new objects with in this). But, the surprising thing is that application page code runs under NTAuthenticateduser account as mentioned by Ali. Hence there is no need to use elevated privileges. Precisely, this is the reason why my update 1 and 2 worked.

Comment: It is very obvious that "user must have at least limited access" because I mentioned that list is on SC1 and we cannot have a user of say site collection 2 or 3 or 4 to have any rights in the 1st site collection. Take it easy my friend.

Comment: OK I can give you that :) But, I will stick to that your non-elevated approach will very possibly give you problems further on if you want to add or update items etc. Therefore it is better to write elevate, or to skip the elevation code all together. Shall we leave it at that? :)

Comment: This was the longest discussion i have ever seen............

Comment: Hi Robert, I have learned from you and some articles that we have to create new objects of spsite and spweb within the runwithelevated code. Look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/13/using-spsite-and-spweb-objects-with-runwithelevatedprivileges-don-t-cross-the-borders.aspx check the last code. Is that wrong? Because the person has not used new for the spweb object.

Comment: Also, because you mentioned it, I am inquisitive about "possibly give you problems further on if you want to add or update items etc". The reason you say this is because I have used the runwithelevated code incorrectly and thus it will get executed as NT Authenticated user (which can access list items), which cannot add/update list items? Did I get it right now?

Comment: Yes, that was all I was arguing with you about. And regarding that blog, not it is a fully functional way, but often it is better to learn the full pattern where you can pass a URL to the constructor of SPSite and then get the web of that URL by using SPSite.OpenWeb() without passing in the url again