# How to check username/accountname under which the code runs?

Tags: permissions, security, runwithelevatedprivileges, application-pool

We want piece of code which we can paste in the code behind and get the username under which code runs for:- (usually .NET code runs under account of application pool)

1. Timer job.
2. Event receiver.
3. Webpart.
4. Layouts application page.
5. User Control
6. JSOM

Then, we want to use RWEP and again check which username code is running under.

What snippet do we use?

**UPDATE**

I do not want code that gives me the username of logged in user. I want the code that will give me the accountname under which the code will run.

**UPDATE**

***For an application page:***

```
  SPUser user1 = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
        string userName1 = user1.Name;
```

Gives value as: Logged in username.

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(idd))
            {
                using (SPWeb rootWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPUser user2 = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
                    string userName2 = user2.Name;
                }

            }
        });
```

Gives value as: Logged in user name.

```
 var User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
        var UserName = User.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value;
```

Gives value as: NT AUTHORITY\IUSR

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(idd))
            {
                using (SPWeb rootWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    var User12 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
                    var UserName12 = User12.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value;                        
                }

            }
        });
```

Gives value as: servername\spadminaccountname

**UPDATE**

(In our case, the site coll. admin username is same as the web application apppool username, so which account is it really?)

1)   Can we conclude that the credentials under which code runs is the 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' and if we use RWEP then the user is 'webapp/sitecol admin user acount'? For example suppose we are accessing a file on the server then, the above 2 accounts will be used to access the file and not the account of logged in user.

2)   Which account is used when accessing SharePoint resources? Is it one of the 2 above or the logged in users credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NotVonKaiser in this case is correct:

1 runs under farm account and all others are under logged in user account!

The logged in user account will call the nt/authenticated account on the server that he/she has authentication on the server todo what he is requesting todo! if that makes sense ;)

think of nt/authenticated as if you are physically logging on to the server todo a specific task like you would on your desktop pc when you power up the machine to logonto windows!

so to make this clear:

2-6 run under current logged in user account that has nt authentication(allowed to access whatever resource is needed)

now saying this, there is another factor involved and that has todo with your web.config and cas policy (code access security policy), depending on what you set (full, partial, low)
will determin the access you would have to the resources under the current logged in account!

> In terms of deployment, the only differences between the full-trust
>   execution model and the bin/CAS execution model are the location where
>   you deploy your assemblies and the code access security policies
>   associated with that location. In both cases, any non-compiled items,
>   such as ASP.NET markup files, XML files, or resource files, are
>   typically deployed to the SharePoint root on each Web front-end
>   server. If you want to deploy a farm solution using either of the farm
>   solution execution models, you must have access to the server file
>   system and be a member of the Farm Administrators security group.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798412.aspx

most code is executed under the current logged in user account.... unless you user reunwithelevatedprivlages than that is somthing else!

now to the question which i belive is somthing more complex and deeper i belive what your looking for it has todo with the worker process!

so you login to the machine -> goto sharepoint site that authenticates your account (nt authentication) -> than you perform a job that is run under the worker process w3wp.exe and i think it is this that your refering to?

> A worker process is user-mode code whose role is to process requests,
>   such as processing requests to return a static page, invoking an ISAPI
>   extension or filter, or running a Common Gateway Interface (CGI)
>   handler.
>
> In both application isolation modes, the worker process is controlled
>   by the WWW service. However, in worker process isolation mode, a
>   worker process runs as an executable file named W3wp.exe, and in IIS
>   5.0 isolation mode, a worker process is hosted by Inetinfo.exe. Figure 2.2, which depicts the architecture for IIS 5.0 isolation mode, uses a dashed line to suggest the relationship between the worker process and
>   the WWW service.
>
> Worker processes use HTTP.sys to receive requests and to send
>   responses by using HTTP. Worker processes also run application code,
>   such as ASP.NET applications and XML Web services. You can configure
>   IIS to run multiple worker processes that serve different application
>   pools concurrently. This design separates applications by process
>   boundaries and helps achieve maximum Web server reliability.
>
> By default, worker processes in worker process isolation mode run
>   under the Network Service account, which has the strongest security
>   (least access) compatible with the functionality that is required.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/29f53968-0115-451f-b26d-5ad58d87b5d1.mspx?mfr=true

so the iis worker process would be the one executing the code at the bottom but to do this in the first place you need to be nt authenticated regarless!

the following link shows a better understanding!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798428.aspx

**EDIT**

> 1) Can we conclude that the credentials under which code runs is the
>   'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' and if we use RWEP then the user is
>   'webapp/sitecol admin user acount'? For example suppose we are
>   accessing a file on the server then, the above 2 accounts will be used
>   to access the file and not the account of logged in user.

ok i think your getting confused?

there are two stages to this.... the user logs into the machine yes? that user has access and is part of 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' so he is able to access specific resources that require you to be 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' within sharepoint..... now running code on the backend of the server will be within w3wp.exe (like .cs code (within assembly))... this is run under the application pool account.. but this wont run unless the logged in user is part of 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. Its not one or the other, more like both at the same time being used.

You know the logged in account that your using obviouslt ;) but to know the w3wp.exe you need to goto the server and goto tast manager, look at processes and find w3wp.exe... you should see the column next to it with the user name which would be the web application pool account.

> 2) Which account is used when accessing SharePoint resources? Is it
>   one of the 2 above or the logged in users credentials?

sharepoint resources are accessed by the logged in user. same as above.

Comment: Can you check the last part of my question.

Comment: just updated the answer! the key here is its not one or the other but a combination of accounts and requestest to resources... sharepoint is complex and so is its permissions.... in sharepoint its a mixture of logged in user as the base and the webapplication in the background... resources like resource files and hive files are based on logged in user account that is part of nt authenticated

Comment: In normal .NET do you remember, suppose we are writting to a text file, then we had to give the write permission to application pool user for that file and NOT to any of the logged in users. I would like to know suppose there is similar requirement in SharePoint, then, which account should be given write permission on file?

Comment: you wouldnt need to give any permission on the file ;) , the file once added into hive should have a group called users and wss_wpg groups. Both should have read access to the resource files... a logged in user would use those accounts to run stuff on the server that the user wouldnt be able to..... What you would change is on sharepoint like in central admin webapplication users or within site collection or site users and groups! If users group is not within webapplication users than they wouldnt have access to resources within hive(access denied).

Comment: HI Ali, Sorry, I meant a file on the server, say in C:\foldername.

Comment: that needs direct access! i use it sometimes to write to a text file on c drive on live server when for some reason it doesnt output any error so i add debug lines into the code to see how far its got to. You need to explicitly add the user in the file permissions under security tab otherwise youll get access denied!

Comment: Which user? Is it the logged in user or apppool user? The site col admin Or the web apppool account user?

Comment: should be the logged in user. so i 'domain\aliSharepoint' sign into sharepoint than it would be that account that needs access to the file!

Comment: Will it be correct to say that, if were not for sharepoint and it was a simple .net site then we needed to give the permission to apppool account to he able to read file.

Answer (score 3):

1 should always run under the farm account.

For 2, 3, 4, and 5, you should be able to ferret this information out by using this code:

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
string userName = user.Name; //you can also call user.Email here
```

Note that this will *not* work correctly if you have a 'RunWithElevatedPrivileges' delegate block. Rather, if you call it within the delegate block, you'll just get the name of the account that is running the code. If you need to supply a username in that case, call the 'SPContext' object before or after you run the delegate block. You won't be able to pass the object into the delegate block directly but you *should* be able to extract what you need into strings or what have you and send *them* in.

For CSOM, assuming you're using JavaScript, this code block comes from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104%28v=office.15%29.aspx) MS page:

```
function getUserProperties() {

// Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

// Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

// Get user properties for the target user.
// To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
// getMyProperties method.
personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

// Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
clientContext.load(personProperties);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {

// Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
    + personProperties.get_displayName();

// Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
    + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
$get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
$get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

You'll have to have SP.js preloaded before this script runs, either by sticking it into the master page or by adding a 'SharePoint:ScriptLink' block for it in your markup.

Basically, what you have to do is this:

1. Call the client context.
2. Tell the client context what you want to retrieve from it.
3. Make an asynchronous call to the web service to get that information.
4. Set up callback methods to handle the data if the async call is successful or not.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just a comment for 3,4,5: Watch out for elevated code (in which case it will be run under the app pool account) or impersonation

Comment: Excellent point! I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I will mark it as answer if you can provide me with a line of code on which I can set by debugger in VS and inspect its contents to check the username under which code will run. The snippet you provided will give me username of logged in user and not the accountname under which the .NET code actually runs.

Comment: Theoretically, I am already aware about the accounts under which the code in Point 1 to 6 run. I want to put a watch and check this myself. Also, I believe that Point 4 (application page) code runs under NT Authenticated user account so your answer (for point 4) will give me current user name and not the username under which code runs which is NT Authenticated user account. Are you getting my point.

Comment: For Point 2: Event receiver code runs in context of user who has triggered the event and not farm account. Am I correct?

Comment: I can tell you for a fact that calling SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser from an application page will retrieve the actual user information of the person accessing the page. I'm on a project right now which has several application pages in it and I have to pass the email address to a process for verification purposes.

Comment: I'll see if I can find the exact property that has the domain/login tomorrow. I *think* it's AccountName but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I believe that For an application page, although it will show you the logged in user name, the actual code runs under the accountname: NT authenticated users. Yes, do let me know on this as this is very important concept a developer must be aware of and I am on hunt for this

Comment: This question obliquely answers this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95825/application-page-in-layouts-folder-accessing-web-application-object. The user's account executes the page. If the page has them attempt to do something they aren't authorized to do and you haven't set up an ElevatePrivileges delegate, they'll get an access denied exception.

Comment: yes, that is my question only, :D

Comment: can you check the updates in question please

Comment: If Event receiver runs under the logged in user account, then why is value of System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User; =NT AUTHORITY\IUSR and not logged in user name?

Comment: (Jumping on an old thread) - Because `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` reflects the app pool and not the actual thread of the user's request - use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` for this.